# Isometric embedding of regular simplex into Riemannian manifold

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $\{v_1,\cdots,v_k\}$ be the vertices of a regular $(k-1)$-simplex $\Delta(k,\ell)$, with a given metric such that the pairwise distance between the vertices is $\ell$.

Given a Riemannian manifold $M^n$. Is there any criterion such that $\Delta(k,\ell)$ can be isometrically embedded in $M$(i.e. preserve the distance, here we only consider the embedding of the vertexes and 1-skeleton).

For example $\Delta(3, \ell)$ can be isometrically embedded into $S^2$ for $\ell$ not too large. $\Delta(4,\ell)$ can only be embedded into $S^2$ with $\ell=\arccos(-1/3)$. What can we say about $\mathbb{CP}^n$ or other symmetric spaces?

Comment: I believe if  $k \leq n+1$ and $l$ is small enough (depending on the injectivity radius) it should be possible.  You can think of build a $k$ simplex by taking successive intersections of $l$ spheres.  If $l$ is smaller than $inj/4$, say, the topology of the intersections of balls should behave how you expect in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Are you asking about an embedding of a simplex or its vertex set?

Comment: @JarekKędra Just the vertex set. Since the distance is preserved, so all the 1- skeleton is embedded.

Comment: To be clear, the 1 skeleton is not embedded isometrically. In $\mathbb R^2$  the distance from the vertex of an equilateral triangle to the midpoint of the opposite segment is smaller than the sidelength $s$ of the triangle. On a sphere the distance is $s$. If you put the intrinsic metric on the embedded 1 skeleton you do get an isometry.

Comment: @TimCarson Yes, you are right. What I actually care about is the complex consists only the vertices and edges, nothing else. I don't know of correct name of this complex other than it is part of the regular simplex.

Comment: I've thought about my first comment a bit and I've only been able to prove it up to $k = 3$.

Comment: @J. GE To be precise, you mean the 1-skeleton with its *intrinsic* metric.